# jslink missing in newform discussion for community

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, community-site

How come jslink is not available for the Newform webpart in a discussion in a Community site template?

[image]

Comment: ok, further investigations shows that the url contains ClientRender=FALSE
When setting this value to true, I can suddenly enter the jslink property, however it is reversed back again, when making a new discussion.
So why is this disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Only way it worked for me is to recreate NewForm using this link
http://platinumdogs.me/2011/12/23/sharepoint-2010-create-and-update-list-forms-programmatically/

Comment: Quote the main aspects from the article as the links tend to go down.